# Value too long exception while changing the datatype size

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Iam trying to changing the column size but getting exception like below. actually the column size is 64 bytes but trying changing to 2 bytes.

ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN column1  type VARCHAR(2);
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(2)

I had verified existing data also the size is less than 2 bytes.

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Even if the data size is less than 2 bytes, postgre won't allow you to do that.

You must manually 'limit' the size of your `varchar`. You can do so with doing substrings of your data. Of course if your column is already 2 bytes long, there won't be any side effect, else it will trim the variables to 2 characters.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN column1 type VARCHAR(2) USING substr(column1, 1, 2)
```

Note that if you want to change the column size to a bigger one, there will be no problems at all.